# To add additional characters to a string obtained from api response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects, fetch-api

I am getting an api response of the form

```
{
    "mobile": [
        {
            "resolution": "S240p",
            "url": "Sample_url1"
        },
        {
            "resolution": "M360p",
            "url": "Sample_url2"
        },
        {
            "resolution": "HD720p",
            "url": "Sample_url3"
        }
    ]
}
```

However from the Front-end i need to display it as S: 240p instead of just S240p , Below is the code in React , Is there any way to achieve this from the Front-End .

```
Mobile.js

isMobile ? dpi_url && 
    dpi_url.mobile.map((value, index) => (
       <Link
            download
            onClick={this.downloadModal}
            href={value.url}
         >                         
         <div className="url_name" key={index}>
            {value.resolution}
         </div>
      </Link>                           
    ))
 : null
```

Expected result should be S: 240p but i am getting S240p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use str.search and regex to find the index of first digit then use substr method to split the string according to your need:

```
const digitIndex = value.resolution.search(/\d/);
const formattedResolution = value.resolution.substr(0,digitIndex)+": "+value.resolution.substr(digitIndex);
```

then display it:

```
<div className="url_name" key={index}>
            {formattedResolution}
 </div>
```

Comment: aravind_reddy :  Hi have updated my query as there were few mistakes in the previous one , i want to display S: 240p , M: 360p and HD: 720p

Answer (score 1):

```js
let mobile = [ { resolution:"S240p" , url:"Sample_url1"} , { resolution:"M360p" , url:"Sample_url2"} ,
{ resolution:"HD720p" , url:"Sample_url3"}] 

let formatted = mobile.map(value => { const sep = isNaN(parseInt(value.resolution[1])) ? `${value.resolution[1]}:` : `:${value.resolution[1]}`;return `${value.resolution[0]}${sep}${value.resolution.substring(2,value.resolution.length)}`})


console.log(formatted)
```

Comment: Hi have updated my query as there were few mistakes in the previous one , i want to display S: 240p , M: 360p and HD: 720p